# Can I change the default template of exporting formats in Spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Spotfire gives the option to export the various analyses in various formats like PDF, Microsoft power point. When I export an analyse, it exports them in default template of these formats(PDF, Microsoft power point).

I need to customize the default template, like need to add a company's logo or background color in the template.

How to achieve this?